# How to read the central Puppet Configurations in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, puppet, puppet-agent

Currently, I am working on a project we are trying to containerize our application. As our current VMs build scripts are pulling the environment and application-related parameters via puppet file related to our application. How do I pull the same values from Puppet while running the Dockerfile?